# How replace text value of textbox in access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have text-box in some form in access 2007.
I am trying to replace all the dots(.) in the text of the text box with some VBA.

This is what i did:

```
Private Sub eng_name_LostFocus()
    Dim val As String
    val = Replace(eng_name.Value, ".", " ")
    eng_name.Value = val
End Sub
```

but its do nothing...

what can i change to work it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub eng_name_AfterUpdate()
    Me!eng_name = Replace(Me!eng_name, ".", " ")
End Sub
```

I think you only need [AfterUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211226%28v=office.11%29.aspx), as it is only triggered when the value of `eng_name` is changed.

I always use Me!ControlName to get/set the value of a control in Access.

Comment: Just tested it, works on Access 2003. Did you registere the AfterUpdate event with the control?

Comment: my mistake...:| the security of the access turns off the VBA. now its works! :P